# Mysql error 1064 while Insert

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm new to MySql. I created a procedure :

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `sampledb`.`InsertSample`
(
    IN aName VARCHAR(20),
    IN aVersion VARCHAR(10),
    IN pName VARCHAR(50),
    OUT InsertStatus VARCHAR(30)
)
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT st.AName FROM sampletable st WHERE st.AName = aName)
    INSERT INTO sampletable(AName, AVersion, PName) 
    VALUES(aName, aVersion, pName)
    SET InsertStatus = 'Success'
ELSE
    SET InsertStatus = 'Already exists!'
END IF
END$$

DELIMITER $$;
```

I tried other way to insert too:

```
 INSERT INTO sampletable (aName, aVersion, pName)
```

Both the times, I got this error:

```
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax ..
```

I'm using MySql 5.0.51b-community-nt

Comment: can you plz provide the full error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is missing a semi-colon( `;` ).

Change

```
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT st.AName FROM sampletable st WHERE st.AName = aName) THEN
    INSERT INTO sampletable(AName, AVersion, PName) 
    VALUES(aName, aVersion, pName)
    SET InsertStatus = 'Success'
ELSE
    SET InsertStatus = 'Already exists!'
END IF
END$$

DELIMITER $$;
```

TO

```
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT st.AName FROM sampletable st WHERE st.AName = aName ) THEN
    INSERT INTO sampletable( AName, AVersion, PName ) 
    VALUES( aName, aVersion, pName );
    SET InsertStatus = 'Success';
ELSE
    SET InsertStatus = 'Already exists!';
END IF;
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

and it should be working.

Comment: @benjamin54 Keyword `THEN` is mandatory and was missing. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `sampledb`.`InsertSample`
(
    IN aName VARCHAR(20),
    IN aVersion VARCHAR(10),
    IN pName VARCHAR(50),
    OUT InsertStatus VARCHAR(30)
)
BEGIN

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT st.AName FROM sampletable st WHERE st.AName = aName) THEN
    INSERT INTO sampletable(AName, AVersion, PName) VALUES(aName, aVersion, pName);
    SET InsertStatus = 'Success';
ELSE SET InsertStatus = 'Already exists!';

END IF;

END$$

DELIMITER $$;
```

You need to ensure you mark the end of each line, and you were missing a THEN clause in your statement